# Need help calculating a column under certain circumstances

Tags: mysql

I'm a noob, so apologies for pending noobisms, etc.

Here's what I'm working with:

This table captures data from a remote sensor including humidity and temperature in celcius . In this case, I'm working specifically with event_type = "Sensor", event_description = "Celsius", and event_data = the temperature in Celsius.

I'd like to create a view that provides a column for converting Celsius to Fahrenheit. (or Kelvin, etc.)

Table columns:

```
   event_id int(11) AI PK

   event_date date 

   event_time time 

   event_type char(50) 

   event_description char(50) 

   event_data char(100) 

   event_platform char(100)
```

Thanks for your help!

```
event_id    event_date  event_time  event_type  event_description   ‌​event_data 
618 2017-11-04  20:17:03    Sensor Celsius  26.2999992371 
617 2017-11-04  20:17:03    Sensor  Humidity    62.0 
616 2017-11-04  19:17:03    Sensor Celsius  27.1000003815 
615 2017-11-04  19:17:03    Sensor  Humidity    59.7000007629 
614 2017-11-04 18:17:03 Sensor  Celsius 28.5 
613 2017-11-04  18:17:03    Sensor  Humidity    56.9000015259 
612 2017-11-04 17:17:03 Sensor  Celsius 31.1000003815 
611 2017-11-04  17:17:03    Sensor  Humidity    51.4000015259
```

Comment: Given that you actually already have rows of data, it would be ever so much easier if you provided a few to use as an example. *& what would the etcetra column(s) be? I presume we cannot predict what they would be*

Comment: event_id event_date event_time event_type event_description event_data
618 2017-11-04 20:17:03 Sensor Celsius 26.2999992371
617 2017-11-04 20:17:03 Sensor Humidity 62.0
616 2017-11-04 19:17:03 Sensor Celsius 27.1000003815
615 2017-11-04 19:17:03 Sensor Humidity 59.7000007629
614 2017-11-04 18:17:03 Sensor Celsius 28.5
613 2017-11-04 18:17:03 Sensor Humidity 56.9000015259
612 2017-11-04 17:17:03 Sensor Celsius 31.1000003815
611 2017-11-04 17:17:03 Sensor Humidity 51.4000015259

Comment: Thanks for the data. If asked for something similar in future, add it to the question, it is usually way too painful to re-use from a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foresee issues with that table's design. Why would numeric data be captured in a char(100) column? That's really not good. Also not sure why you are using so many fixed width char columns that will be a large waste of storage.

```
select
    event_type
  , event_date date 
  , event_time time 
  , event_description
  , event_data as Celcius
  , cast(event_data as decimal(12,3)) * 1.8 + 32 as Fahrenheit
  , cast(event_data as decimal(12,3)) + 273.15 as Kelvin
from yourtable
where event_type = 'Sensor'
and event_description = 'Celsius'
```

nb: the choice of decimal(12,3) has no science to it, just where my fingers landed

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this asap!
Re. event_data, inc this case it's Celsius temperature, but in another case it might be a message string, like event_type = "system", event_description = "startup", event_data = "system startup, no errors"

Comment: `event_data = "system startup, no errors"` I know why you have used strings, but you will learn to regret using that for numeric data. At some point the numbers will not "convert" (maybe a zero is an O instead) then things go from bad to worse. Anyway, don't use CHAR (fixed width) there's no point in doing that.